# Set Visual Studio to not save Project Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express

I have a Windows Form application that I'm working on and I have some settings that a user is prompted for the first time that they use the application.  (The settings that are created by looking at the project properties).

What I'm trying to do for testing purposes is have those show up everytime that I enter debug mode, but at the moment it is actually saving them for me so I only see it the one time.

I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have the dialog already, but don't know how to find out if you are in debug mode.

One way is to use the preprocessor

```
#if DEBUG
    // The debug code here
#else
    // The release code here
#endif
```

This way the application compiles different depending on the solution configuration combo in Visual Studio. If you take the debug build and starts it from outside visual studio you will still run the DEBUG part.

The other possibility is to check if you have a debugger attached.

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // The debug code here
}
else
{
    // The release code here
}
```

This way the behavior changes if you start from Visual Studio or not. You can start the release build from Visual Studio (or attach a debugger after you have started the application) and still come to the debug-part.

Most likely the second alternative is what you want, but if you want to be able to send a test-binary to your customer with the debug behavior the first alternative is the way to go.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would fix my issue (I may just not be seeing it).  I don't want the code to behave differently.  I just don't want Visual Studio to actually save the resources that I have beyond that debugging session.  So I have code similar to `Payroll.Properties.Settings.Default.HasToLogIn` and I'd like for Visual Studio to only save the values for the duration of the debugging session and then have them reset to their default values whenever I enter debug mode again.  I suppose I could use the code provided above to set the defaults at launch... I'd prefer not to do this if possible.

Comment: @Jared This is the solution. Just check if its debug then delete the properties and prompt for it again. If its not debug just let it act normal.